# Prevent swift closure from retain/release on closure's argument?

Tags: swift, closures, automatic-ref-counting

I've the following line:

```
if let obj = renderGroup.objects.first(where: {$0.elementId == elementId}) {
```

This line gets called a lot and the whole operation takes too long, so I've started profiling it.
I noticed that more than half of the time is spend in `swift_retain` and `swift_release`, all on this single line. `elementId` are both an `Int64`, but `$0` is a class (hence reference type). So it seems that the retain and release are used for the `$0` argument.

This doesn't seem very useful, as the argument wil always be around for the lifetime of the `first()` call.

Is there a way to prevent all the retain and release calls on the argument?

Comment: Just in case you aren't: is this on a release build with optimisations?

Comment: Yes, it is a release build.